# What is a verb to the noun "shortage" or the adjective "scarce"?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there any verb to use that means "to create a shortage" or "to make scarce". Scarcify? Shorten? They sound weird and I would be surprised if there was not a word for this. Was unable to find anything until now.

Comment: Interesting. I don't think there is a word 'to make extinct' either.

Comment: It's nearly always a typo for ***sanctified***, but... [*It finally came to be accepted by the leading editorial minds that pictures of glorified girls in **scantified** bathing suits and occasional references to the reigning queens of tennis were insufficient coverage ...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22scantified+bathing%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Deplete*, the meanings of which, according to the OED, include "to  reduce the fullness of, to deprive of contents or supplies"

Comment: This is perfect!

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deplete) gives a usage note highlighting the 'reduction to a parlous degree' implication: << deplete, drain, exhaust, impoverish, bankrupt mean to deprive of something essential to existence or potency. deplete implies a reduction in number or quantity so as to endanger the ability to function. ⟨depleting our natural resources⟩ >>

Comment: Would anyone know a word then that means deplete, but without the endangering element to it?